# The units do not match with the coordinate system while drawing circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I have drawn a set of circles in GeoGebra. It looks like this:
[image]

And I would like to draw the same picture in TikZ. Thus, I enter the coordinate of the centers, and draw using `minimum width` parameter. This is what I write:

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{disk} = [draw, thick, circle,fill=none]
    \node (A) at (-4,1) [disk, minimum width=20] {};
    \node (B) at (2,0) [disk, minimum width=70] {};     
    \node (C) at (0,6) [disk, minimum width=40] {};
    \node (D) at (8,2) [disk, minimum width=20] {};
    \node (E) at (8,-6) [disk, minimum width=80] {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

How can I match the coordinate system units with width?

If I use millimeters as the units, the circles grow, but still do not intersect:

[image]

Comment: Just add mm after the units.

Comment: @marmot did not work. please see the second figure.

Comment: Sorry! My bad! I missed the fact that there is a factor 2. If you look for instance at your circle around A, you see it has radius 2 (in whatever units), corresponding to diameter (or minimum width) 4. If these units are cm, which Ti*k*Z implicitly assumes if you put no units at the coordinates, this means you need to use 40 mm for this circle, and multiply all other `minimun width`s by 2 and add mm.

Comment: Actually, I got what I wanted by fixing `x=1cm, y=1cm` and using `\draw (0,0) circle (2cm)` instead of `\node` command.

Comment: Typically any options must be given units (default is pt).  Only (x,y) coordinates use the scale factors (default=1cm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what I wanted by fixing `x=1cm, y=1cm` and using `\draw (0,0) circle (2cm)` instead of `\node` command.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, scale=0.5] % scale to prevent overflow
    \draw (-4,2) circle (2cm);
    \draw (2,0)  circle (7cm);      
    \draw (0,6)  circle (4cm);
    \draw (8,2)  circle (2cm);
    \draw (8,-6)  circle (8cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: why scale? use`x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm`

Comment: @Zarko I think you meant `x=2, y=2`. But that does not work as well, since the distances are not preserved.

Comment: `x=1cm,y=1cm` is actually the default, so you don't need those.